# Map data java OSM

Tags: java, google-maps, gis, openstreetmap

I'm new to open street maps and GIS. Is there a java API avaliable for Open street maps?
From what I can see they are geared towards editing maps, I only want to retrieve data and display it.
if I'm understanding it correctly I should:
Send a http request
Receive XML
parse this XMl (somehow?)
render this as a map(any library recommendations?)

THanks

Comment: have a look at https://trac.openstreetmap.org/browser/applications/utils/LiveEditMapViewer , you might find something useful in this project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you be OK with simply showing pre-rendered tiles, or do you need to process the data into some new visualisation format? If the former, you can just grab PNGs [from a Tileserver](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Deploying_your_own_Slippy_Map#Sources_of_tiles). If the latter, yes you'd query the XML data from something like [Overpass](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API), and then it's up to you to parse the XML data and do things with it.

I find that XSLT is a nice way to specify how to convert the raw XML into a more amenable form ([here's a simple OSM XSLT from me](https://github.com/danstowell/pubdensity/blob/master/osm_pub_csv.xslt)).

Comment: I think pre-rendered tiles would be okay, although I'd like the user to be able to zoom in and out and I'm not sure that would be possible with pre-rendered tiles if it's just an image file?

Comment: After a bit more reading, looks like they do offer zoom, could be what I need thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try JOSM ? 
It is open source desktop application whose primary purpose is editing of OSM data, but I have used it to display maps in my own GUI. I have made a fork to JOSM (https://github.com/zmau/josm), and there I have enabled disabling of its own GUI, and made some other tweaks. 
After that, I have put their MapView control onto my swing window (in my project which references this forked JOSM variation), and successfully displayed a map on it.
(If you take a look at commits in my fork, you'll find more changes than you need, because I have used josm to display map on some very specific device, and you do not need that.)